# IF EXIST - Files Without an Extension

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop, dir

A working script that moves various files based on file name runs successfully. After the script is done it will check two directories for any lingering files using `IF EXIST *.txt`. This works great except I've noticed some files with no extension. These were not an issue before and since that cannot be helped due to processes out of my control, I need to amend my script.

My only idea is the following code. Bear with as there are two conditions:

```
:check1
PUSHD "\\UNC\path1" &&(
DIR /A-D *.
IF %errorlevel% NEQ 0 GOTO check2
) & POPD

:add1
ECHO Add note to the log file

:check2
PUSHD "\\UNC\path2" &&(
DIR /A-D *.
IF %errorlevel% NEQ 0 GOTO laststep
) & POPD

:add2
ECHO Add note to the log file

:laststep
Some other code before exiting
```

This should run `DIR` on the path and if files without extensions exist, it will have `%errorlevel%` zero and move on to the next check. If there are **no** files present, it will have `%errorlevel%` not zero (likely 1) and it will append some text to the log before the next check. Check two will do the same.

This seems to be awfully complicated and I am not able to find a "one-liner" solution that is as easy as `IF EXIST`. I realize I can use `*.` but that returns directories as well and may result in an incorrect `%errorlevel%`.

**Updated Code**

Where I normally set my variables, I also `SET` the two paths to run `DIR` against. This way they can be used more easily elsewhere *and* I bypass the UNC Path error I normally get - reasons for that are unknown to me. The updated file check, used only for files without an extension, is:

```
DIR %p1% /b /a-d|FIND /v "." && ECHO Found 1 >> %log%
DIR %p2% /b /a-d|FIND /v "." && ECHO Found 2 >> %log%
FINDSTR /I "Found" %log%
IF %errorlevel% EQU 0 GOTO stillthere

:nofiles
Some code
GOTO domore

:stillthere
Some code

:domore
Other code before exit
```

Thank you for the responses, I've learned from this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want to find?

```
dir /b /a-d |find /v "."
```

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:check1
PUSHD "u:\path1"
DIR /A-D *. >NUL 2>NUL
IF %errorlevel% EQU 0 ECHO Add note \path1 to the log file
POPD

PUSHD "u:\path2"
DIR /A-D *. >NUL 2>NUL
IF %errorlevel% EQU 0 ECHO Add note \path2 to the log file
POPD

:laststep
:: Some other code before exiting

GOTO :EOF
```

Your problems include:

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

and you are potentially jumping out of a `PUSHD/POPD` bracket which would mean your `POPD` won't necessarily restore your starting directory.

(Note that I used `u:\` rather than a server to suit my system)

Comment: This is great info! It didn't occur to me that could potentially skip over the `POPD` and jump out of sequence. So much to learn and maybe some more review. Ultimately I will use your suggestion for another script I've been asked to write; thank you. For this particular request I've ended up changing out the lines in question with @foxidrive 's updated `DIR` command.

Answer (score 0):

You are already using `&&` to verify `PUSHD` worked. You can do the same with your `DIR /-D`. I find it makes life easier. Also, you probably want to hide any error message if `*.` is not found, especially since that is the expected condition. I also hid the display of any files that might be found, but you can certainly get rid of that redirection. You might also want to hide error message if PUSHD fails, but I didn't implement that.

```
PUSHD "\\UNC\path1" && (
  DIR /A-D *. 1>nul 2>nul && ECHO Add note to the log file
  POPD
)

PUSHD "\\UNC\path2" && (
  DIR /A-D *. 1>nul 2>nul && ECHO Add note to the log file
  POPD
)

ECHO Some other code before exiting
```